# A club with 17 women and 21 men needs to form a committee of size 7

Tags: combinatorics

A club with 17 women and 21 men needs to form a committee of size 7:

I understand that 12,620,256 committees are possible what I cannot figure out is how many committees of seven different executive positions are possible? (e.g.,
chair, treasurer, secretary, etc.)

This is all the information that I've been given.

Comment: You have a pool of $38$ people. You can choose any one of them to be the chair. Once that’s done, you can choose the treasurer in $37$ different ways. And so on. Can you take it from there?

Comment: would this be just 38 * 37 * 36 * 35 * 34 * 33 * 32?  It doesn't seem right, I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: You’re not missing a thing: that’s exactly right.

Comment: Ah well thanks then.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The number of committees **without** order significance:

$$\binom{38}{7}=\frac{38!}{(7!)\cdot(38-7)!}=12620256$$

The number of committees **with** order significance:

$$\binom{38}{7}\cdot(7!)=\frac{38!}{(38-7)!}=63606090240$$